# How to reduce jitter for Java?

Tags: java, linux, real-time

To resolve this issue I have created an open source [Java Thread Affinity library](https://github.com/peter-lawrey/Java-Thread-Affinity)

When I have a number of thread interacting closely it can reduce latency and increase throughput.  For single threaded tasks it can still reduce jitter quite a bit.

---

This program looks at the difference in time between calls to `System.nanoTime()` and reports those over 10x,000 ns.

```
public class TimeJumpingMain {
    static final long IGNORE_TIME = 1000 * 1000 * 1000; // the first second to allow warmup.
    static final int minJump = 10; // smallest jump of 10 us.
    static final int midJump = 100; // mid size jump of 100 us.
    static final int bigJump = 1000; // big jump of 1 ms.

    public static void main(String... args) {
        int[] intervalTimings = new int[1000];
        int[] jumpTimings = new int[1000];

        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long prev = start;
        long prevJump = start;
        int jumpCount = 0;
        int midJumpCount = 0;
        int bigJumpCount = 0;

        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            long jump = (now - prev) / 1000;
            if (jump > minJump && now - start > IGNORE_TIME) {
                long interval = (now - prevJump) / 1000;
                if (jumpCount < intervalTimings.length) {
                    intervalTimings[jumpCount] = (int) interval;
                    jumpTimings[jumpCount] = (int) jump;
                }
                if (jump >= midJump)
                    midJumpCount++;
                if (jump >= bigJump)
                    bigJumpCount++;
                prevJump = now;
                jumpCount++;
            }
            prev = now;
            if (now - start > 120L * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + IGNORE_TIME)
                break;
        }
        System.out.println("interval us\tdelay us");
        for (int i = 0; i < jumpCount && i < intervalTimings.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(intervalTimings[i] + "\t" + jumpTimings[i]);
        }
        System.out.printf("Time jumped %,d / %,d / %,d times by at least %,d / %,d / %,d us in %.1f seconds %n",
                jumpCount, midJumpCount, bigJumpCount, minJump, midJump, bigJump, (System.nanoTime() - start - IGNORE_TIME) / 1e9);
    }
}
```

on my machine this reports

```
Time jumped 2,905 / 131 / 20 times by at least 10 / 100 / 1,000 us in 120.0 seconds
```

I have tried `chrt` to set real time priority and `taskset` to try to lock to a single core AFTER STARTING the process but these didn't help as I expected.

I configured the box to move all interrupts to cpus 0-3 and the cpu mask for all process with 0xFF to 0x0F.  In `top` the first four cpus are ~99% idle and the last four cpus are 100.0% idle.

Using `chrt -r 99` as root

```
Time jumped 673 / 378 / 44 times by at least 10 / 100 / 1,000 us in 120.0 seconds
```

However, when using `taskset -c 7` alone (I have made sure cpu7 is free)

```
Time jumped 24 / 1 / 0 times by at least 10 / 100 / 1,000 us in 120.0 seconds
```

Using `chrt - r 99 taskset -c 7`

```
Time jumped 7 / 1 / 0 times by at least 10 / 100 / 1,000 us in 120.0 seconds
```

It appears that trying to use taskset after the process had started wasn't working for me.

The broader question is;

How to reduce jitter for a Java process?  Are there any more tips for reducing jitter on Linux?

NOTE: No GC occurs during the running of this process (checked with -verbosegc)

It appears that code compiling may cause a delay of 3.62 ms every time after 100 - 102 ms. For this reason I ignore everything in the first second as warmup.

Comment: try not to print in the hot loop, just add the result into an arraylist to reduce the system calls. also did you check for the compiler kick-in?

Comment: *It appears that trying to use taskset after the process had started wasn't working for me.*  I never managed to make it work (after), so if I need CPU affinity I rely on preselecting it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's system jitter and JVM jitter.

For the former you can use the isolcpus parameter at boot time to ensure that nothing but your application code can run on those cpus

http://www.novell.com/support/viewContent.do?externalId=7009596&sliceId=1

Ideally you'd do a jni call (to your own jni lib) down to `sched_setaffinity` just for the active thread so that you really do have nothing but that thread running there.

In my experience, system jitter is minimised by use of isolcpus with interrupts handled by specific cores only, hyper threading switched off and absolutely all use of power management removed (these are bios options when they're available to turn off all the c-state & p-state management) while running your app on shielded cores. The bios specific options are obviously specific to your motherboard so you'll need to look into that based on your motherboard model.

Another thing look at at the system level is the local APIC interrupt (LOC, local interrupt counter) frequency. Is this a "low latency desktop" using 1kHz interrupts? either way, you can expect jitter to be clustered around the interrupt interval

2 more I know practically nothing about but am aware of as sources of jitter; kernel tlb flush interrupts and userspace tlb flush interrupts. Some RT kernels offer options to control these so this might be another thing to look into. You can also look at [this site](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/articles/b/u/i/HOWTO~_Build_an_RT-application_6066.html) about building RT apps on the RT kernel for more tips.

Comment: The LOC is 100 Hz.  I would be very interested if there is a way to turn these off, however they don't appear to cause too much overhead. Have you tried this with CentOS? http://editthis.info/wiki/User:Ascensus (Are you the matt here?) Any advise for using isolcpus with centos?

Comment: @PeterLawrey (and Matt), aside the "OS" imposed spikes, java and RT is a hard one since both the compiler and the GC need to run w/ higher priority, yet that's not available normally for Linux. While there are some efforts to run microseconds GC cycles by IBM, warming up all code paths so the compiler doesn't (de)optimize anything may prove hard.

Comment: different matt. I haven't tried this with centos, assuming you have an SMP kernel and you ensure isolcpus is set as a kernel param at boot time then it should just work. YMMV of course! The LOC overhead at 100Hz should be small but you are likely to get jitter every 10ms as a result, you can't turn it off (afaik)

Comment: I have script which tasksets all processes and sets the smp_affinity of interrupts.  IT appears to give me the same as isolcpus without the reboot.  Once I am happy with it, this option sounds the best way to be able to set it on reboot.